# How to add an api results to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, api

I'm working on a project and trying to find a way to add my api results to mysql.

Here is [the page](http://www.jobsinsac.com/api/api_notification.php) were you can find the results.

Here is the code of the page:

```
    <?php
///PLOT PROJECT USER REQUEST

//HELPER FUNCTION TO PRINT TO CONSOLE
function debug_to_console( $data ) {

    if ( is_array( $data ) )
        $output = "<script>console.log( 'Debug Objects: " . implode( ',', $data) . "' );</script>";
    else
        $output = "<script>console.log( 'Debug Objects: " . $data . "' );</script>";

    echo $output;
}

//PLOT PROJECT REQUEST 
$appId = '9fed0c75ca624e86a411b48ab27b3d5a';
$private_token = 'VGjPehPNBa5henSa';
$qry_str = "/api/v1/account/";

$ch = curl_init();
$headers = array(
'Content-Type:application/json',
'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode($appId.":".$private_token) // <---
);

$geofenceId = '736cb24a1dae442e943f2edcf353ccc7'; 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://admin.plotprojects.com/api/v1/notification/?geofenceId=' . $geofenceId); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, '3');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip');

$content = trim(curl_exec($ch));
curl_close($ch);
print $content;

?>
```

Comment: Please tell us what you've tried so far.

Comment: So just take the response, `json_decode()` it, and add it to the appropriate mysql table/columns?

Comment: do you solve your problem?

Comment: No i haven't resolved this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_decode()` to decode your JSON string and take the values that you need to make your query. Read more at:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

  ```
  <?php

  //The response from http://www.jobsinsac.com/api/api_notification.php

  $json = '{ "success": true, "result": { "data": [{ "placeId": "736cb24a1dae442e943f2edcf353ccc7", "cooldownDays": 0, "triggerTimes": "inherit", "state": "published", "cooldownSeconds": 1, "data": "http://www.illuminatimc.com", "enabled": true, "geofenceId": "736cb24a1dae442e943f2edcf353ccc7", "id": "0cad6b54d225459e85cd8c27567f8b0b", "message": "Get a cold beer, for $2.00, shots for $4.00, come inside, up stairs.", "created": "2015-03-17T18:54:41Z", "timespans": [], "handlerType": "landingPage", "trigger": "enter" }], "total": 1 } }';

  $data = json_decode($json, true);

  print_r($data);

  ?>
  ```

  Output:

  ```
  Array
  (
      [success] => 1
      [result] => Array
          (
              [data] => Array
                  (
                      [0] => Array
                          (
                              [placeId] => 736cb24a1dae442e943f2edcf353ccc7
                              [cooldownDays] => 0
                              [triggerTimes] => inherit
                              [state] => published
                              [cooldownSeconds] => 1
                              [data] => http://www.illuminatimc.com
                              [enabled] => 1
                              [geofenceId] => 736cb24a1dae442e943f2edcf353ccc7
                              [id] => 0cad6b54d225459e85cd8c27567f8b0b
                              [message] => Get a cold beer, for $2.00, shots for $4.00, come inside, up stairs.
                              [created] => 2015-03-17T18:54:41Z
                              [timespans] => Array
                                  (
                                  )

                              [handlerType] => landingPage
                              [trigger] => enter
                          )

                  )

              [total] => 1
          )

  )
  ```